# Htaccess : URL Rewriting not causing 404 on nonexisting pages and not working as expected

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, model-view-controller

Server path is:

**FTP :** htaccess is in `root/` and `index.php` is in `root/www/`.

**Real path (using getcwd) :** `index.php` is in `/home/mysite/www`.
I'm using a clustered web hosting.

Here is the code I wrote (working) to have readable links:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
#Https redirect

Options All -Indexes 
#Prevents access to server files -- unusual behavior doesn't stop if removed

RewriteRule (^azazaz|placeholdercateg)/?([0-9]+)?/?$ /index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
#Internally redirects mysite.com/placeholdercateg to mysite.com/index.php?category=placeholdercateg or mysite.com/placeholdercateg/pagenumber to mysite.com/index.php?category=placeholdercateg&page=pagenumber

RewriteRule (^azazaz|placeholdercateg)/?(^azaza|placeholderaction)/?([0-9]+)/?([0-9]+)?$ /index.php?category=$1&action=$2&id=$3&postid=$4 [NC,L]
#Same as first RewriteRule, but for user interaction
```

**Problem 1 : (solved, see below)**
For some reason, if someone enters `index.php` in the URL-to-be-rewritten (e.g : `mysite.com/placeholdercateg/index.php`), the URL changes itself to `mysite.com/www/placeholdercateg`, then if they enter `index.php` again, it changes itself to `mysite.com/www/www/placeholdercateg` ad infinitum. As expected, though, `mysite.com/index.php` is met with 404.

**Problem 2 :**
Another unusual behavior that I can't wrap my head around : nonexisting pages aren't met with 404 (eg : `mysite.com/icanliterallywriteanything/notevenkidding/placeholdercateg`), the page just shows `mysite.com/placeholdercateg` but the URL still shows up as changed.

It's rather distressing and I'd like to fix these issues. Any suggestions?

- **What is `(^azazaz)` for?**

I don't understand why, but the first statement in a RewriteRule always leads to a 404 error in my case, even if it's something that is supposed to exist. For example, if the RewriteRule is `(^placeholdercateg)/etc` and I go to `mysite.com/placeholdercateg`, it's an immediate 404.

This is why I use "azazaz" as the first statement and "placeholdercateg" as the second, as it only blocks the first statement and the rule works for the second. I would also like to know more about this, but this is not my primary concern at the moment.

- **Why haven't you tried to use already existing files or folders to rewrite your URLs?**

Because there aren't. I'm using an MVC pattern.

- **Do you have any other Rules apart from these?**

(added)

- **Mention path of your index.php and htaccess also where are they residing in server.**

(added)

- **Attempt 1 with @RavinderSingh13's solution :** https://stackoverflow.com/a/68480103/16499978

**Attempt :** `mysite.com/index.php` ==> index.php is accessed (home page)

**Attempt :** `mysite.com/placeholdercateg/index.php` ==> 404 not found (**problem 1 solved**)

**Attempt :** `mysite.com/anythingreally/reallyanything/etc/placeholdercateg/` ==> placeholdercateg page is accessed

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your efforts. Could you please confirm 2 things, 1st- Do you have any other Rules apart from these?(if yes then add complete htaccess in your question). 2nd- Mention path of your index.php and htaccess also where are they residing in server.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the welcome and quick response. I just added those details. I can't access the real path of .htaccess though. I am going to try to relocate .htaccess to /www/ to see if there is a change.

Comment: Can you share your `VirtualHost` config in question or tell what path is `DocumentRoot` set to?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to do this. I can't temper with my server using commands or anything due to the nature of my web hosting, I just have an FTP where a basic configuration file is located in root, containing ```app.engine=php
app.engine.version=7.4

http.firewall=security
environment=development

container.image=stable```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown attempts, samples; please try following htaccess Rules in your rule file. Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On
Options All -Indexes -MultiViews

#Https redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^index.php/?$ - [F,NC,L]

#Prevents access to server files -- unusual behavior doesn't stop if removed
#Internally redirects mysite.com/placeholdercateg to mysite.com/index.php?category=placeholdercateg or mysite.com/placeholdercateg/pagenumber to mysite.com/index.php?category=placeholdercateg&page=pagenumber
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (^azazaz|placeholdercateg)/?([0-9]+)?/?$ /home/mysite/www/index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]

#Same as first RewriteRule, but for user interaction
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (^azazaz|placeholdercateg)/?(^azaza|placeholderaction)/?([0-9]+)/?([0-9]+)?$ /home/mysite/www/index.php?category=$1&action=$2&id=$3&postid=$4 [NC,L]

##New rules for non-existing uris.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*/([\w-]+)/?$ /$1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?param=$1 [QSA,L]
```